# D3js vertical and horizontal custom line display overflow in zoombable chart

Tags: d3.js

For my project, I had to create a point chart with two set of lines (the first one which copprespond to the d3js axis coordinates in the chart as basic information and another custom one with particular decimal offsets.

So I have created my axis X and Y and corresponding lines in the graph, the second set of line with corresponding X and Y coordinates and finally the zoom.

Result, everything works fine despite my second set of lines is overflowing the chart when I zoom/pan. It looks like lines are only disappearing when they go out of the entire SVG element.

Here is the code:

```
let margin = { top: 8, right: 50, bottom: 22, left: 70 },
  width = 1140 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 560 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, this.area.length])
  .range([0, width]);

let yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([+(this.area.width / 2), -(this.area.width / 2)])
  .range([height, 0]);

let formatAxis = d3.format('.0f');

let xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient('bottom')
  .ticks(10)
  .tickFormat(formatAxis)
  .innerTickSize(-height)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

let yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient('left')
  .ticks(6)
  .tickFormat(formatAxis)
  .innerTickSize(-width)
  .outerTickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(10);

  // create the svg
let svg = d3.select('.chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  // add X axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'x axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

  // add Y axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(yAxis);

// function to create X lines
let make_x_line = (i: number) => {
  svg.append('line')
    .attr('y1', yScale(+(this.area.width / 2)))
    .attr('y2', yScale(-(this.area.width / 2)))
    .attr('x1', xScale(this.xValueData[i]))
    .attr('x2', xScale(this.xValueData[i]))
    .attr('class', 'xline' + i)
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2.5)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
};

// function to create Y lines
let make_y_line = (i: number) => {
  svg.append('line')
    .attr('y1', yScale(this.yValueData[i]))
    .attr('y2', yScale(this.yValueData[i]))
    .attr('x1', xScale(0))
    .attr('x2', xScale(this.area.length))
    .attr('class', 'yline' + i)
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2.5)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
};

// function zoom
let zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(xScale)
  .y(yScale)
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on('zoom', () => {
    d3.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
    d3.select('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.xValueData.length; i++) {
      d3.select('.xline' + i).attr('y1', yScale(+(this.area.width / 2)))
        .attr('y2', yScale(-(this.area.width / 2)))
        .attr('x1', xScale(this.xValueData[i]))
        .attr('x2', xScale(this.xValueData[i]));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.yValueData.length; i++) {
      d3.select('.yline' + i).attr('y1', yScale(this.yValueData[i]))
        .attr('y2', yScale(this.yValueData[i]))
        .attr('x1', xScale(0))
        .attr('x2', xScale(this.area.length));
    }
  });

// lines for the grid selection and point creation in X
for (let i = 0; i < this.xValueData.length; i++) {
  make_x_line(i);
}

// // // lines for the grid selection and point creation in Y
for (let i = 0; i < this.yValueData.length; i++) {
  make_y_line(i);
}

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', 'transparent')
  .attr('class', 'pane')
  .call(zoom)
  });
```

Here is the result:
[image: normal chart]

Here is the display when I zoom:
[image: zoomed chart]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [clip path](http://www.d3noob.org/2015/07/clipped-paths-in-d3js-aka-clippath.html), also would be a great idea to add the lines to a [group](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-group-element-and-d3js), so it would be easier to handle them.

So what I would do is create a clip path and new groups for the vertical and horizontal lines too and set the clip-path attribute. Like this:

```
svg.append('clipPath').attr('id', 'clip').append('rect').attr('x', 0).attr('y',0).attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
let verticalLines = svg.append('g').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)').attr('class', 'verticalLines');
let horizontalLines= svg.append('g').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)').attr('class', 'horizontalLines');
```

And finally in your loop you would add the lines to the groups above like this:

```
  let make_x_line = (i: number) => {
  verticalLines.append('line')
    .attr('y1', yScale(+(this.area.width / 2)))
    .attr('y2', yScale(-(this.area.width / 2)))
    .attr('x1', xScale(this.xValueData[i]))
    .attr('x2', xScale(this.xValueData[i]))
    .attr('class', 'xline' + i)
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2.5)
    .attr('fill', 'none');
};
```